# Separar uma única string em um array de strings

Tags: c, array, string

Nesse código estou tentando fazer com que uma string seja lida e então colocar cada palavra separada por espaço em um array de strings. Vi que em alguns casos se usa a função strtok, mas como eu pretendo usar essas strings para outras funções, eu não sei como utilizar a strtok corretamente.
No código a variável "strings" não está recebendo corretamente os caracteres da "string", o que está errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
 int N, i, j, k=0, l=0;
 scanf ("%d", &N); //número de casos de teste
 for (i=1; i<=N; i++)
 {      
    char string[50];
    int palavras=1;
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets (string, 50, stdin);
    for(j=0; string[j]!='\0'; j++)
    {
        if (string[j]==' ')
        {
            palavras++;
        }
    }
    char strings[palavras][50];
    for (j=0; string[j]!='\0'; j++)
    {
        if (string[j] == ' ')
        {
            l=0;
            k++;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            strings[k][l] = string[j];
            l++;
        }
    }
    for (j=0; j<palavras; j++)
    {
        puts (strings[j]);
    }
 } 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Oi, amigo 
Não teria como utilizar o método "String.split()", na sua aplicação ?

`String frase = "nome teste 10";
 String array[] = new String[3];
 array = frase.split(" ");`

array[0] -> nome;

Comment: Acredito que isso seja em Python, logo não poderei aplicar esse método em meu código